# Fortran 90 compiling issue: undefined reference to <modulename>

Tags: module, compiler-errors, fortran, fortran90

I'm having trouble trying to compile a simple fortran program which uses a module in the same directory.
I have 2 files: test1.f90 which contains the program and modtest.f90 which contains the module.

This is test1.f90:

```
program test
  use modtest
  implicit none
  print*,a
end program test
```

This is modtest.f90:

```
module modtest
  implicit none
  save
  integer :: a = 1
end module modtest
```

Both files are in the same directory. I compile modtest.f90 and test.f90 like this:

```
gfortran -c modtest.f90
gfortran -o test1 test1.f90
```

But then I get this error:

```
/tmp/cckqu8c3.o: In function `MAIN__':
test1.f90:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `__modtest_MOD_a'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Or: `gfortran modtest.f90 test1.f90 -o test1`

Comment: @PreetSangha: I do not understand what you are saying. (What about programming questions? By "So", do you mean "StackOverflow" — if so, it should be "SO". Ask what if you don't know what?)

Comment: The comment I replied to seems to have been deleted. I think that person was asking why building  was a programming question.Anyway it nearly a decade ago:-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're doing is not telling the linker where reference module `modtest` is so that the your code can use its contents.

This should work:

```
gfortran -o test1 test1.f90 modtest.o
```

Some context:

The `-o` option tells the compiler to put the output of the full build (compile + link) into a program called `test1`. Then we supply a file that we are to compile (`test1.f90`). Finally we are telling the compiler to consider a file that contains the compiled output of another build (`modtest.o`) and to link this to the compiled output of `test1.f90`, and use the contents of `modtest.o` when trying to sort out references within the test1.f90 that reference the module `modtest` (in the statement `use modtest` in the source code).

So the statement says:

Please compile and subsequently link `test1.f90` to `modtest.o`, and produce a file called `test1` as the final output.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! I've been learning Fortran for a month now, I can't believe I didn't know that :P

Comment: While this command does solve the problem, some description should be provided. I will be happy to retract my downvote once the answer is improved.

Comment: The solution is not enough - please provide some context as to _why_ this solves the problem.

Comment: I used this as a basis to compile a much larger project but am getting the same problem. Will this work for programs using modules that use other modules? Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870715/building-large-program-in-gfortran

Comment: You would have to look that the options for gfortran and see if there are extra options you need.