# Error: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" using external function in Fortran

Tags: fortran, x86-64, undefined-symbol

I am learning Fortran and trying to use external function in the main program. Compilation works fine, but after attempting to build the program I get following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fib_fun_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccuWur6l.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to rewrite the program several times, but it hasn’t worked. As I do not have much experience in programming I don’t really know what else I can change and how to make it work.

Here a is the main code:

```
PROGRAM fibonacci 

IMPLICIT NONE

real :: x
real :: y
logical :: wahl = .TRUE.

do while(wahl .eqv. .TRUE.) 

write (*,*)
write (*,*) "Enter a number: "
read (*,*) x 

! Computation
call fib_fun(x, y)
write (*,*) "Last number of the Fibonacci-Sequence: ", y

write (*,*)
write (*,*) "Start new commutation?"
read (*,*) wahl

end do

END PROGRAM fibonacci
```

This is the external function as a separate file, that I am trying to use in the main code:

```
FUNCTION fib_fun(ein, aus)

integer :: j
integer :: ein
real :: aus
real :: fib_zahl(100)

fib_zahl(1) = 1
fib_zahl(2) = 1

do j = 1, ein
fib_zahl(j+2) = fib_zahl(j) + fib_zahl(j+1)
end do 

aus = fib_zahl(ein) 

END FUNCTION fib_fun
```

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should always show the commands that you run where you got the error. If not too long, show the command and its complete output, We need to know *how* you attempted to build the program when you got the error.

Comment: BTW, if you are learning programming, start by putting your functions in modules. My students were not even shown the existence of extenal functions this semester yet. Modules are to be learned first.

Comment: Potential duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641684/fortran-link-error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904814/fortran-90-compiling-issue-undefined-reference-to-modulename

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

Here is what I type in terminal to build the program:

`gfortran fib_main.f95 -o fib_main.exe`

After that I get that error I described above.

Comment: Your `gfortran` command doesn't include the file with the external function.  Thus it's not found when `gfortran` tries to link the final executable out of the inputs you gave it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fortran link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641684/fortran-link-error)

Comment: You're also calling it as a subroutine but defining it as a function, so it probably still won't work after giving the compiler both input files.  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_procedures_and_functions.  Also your main code doesn't do anything to let the compiler know what types the called function is expecting, and you're using `call` with two `real` args, but then the function (which should be a subroutine) is expecting one of the args to be integer, not `real`.